# Java - Opening a new View from a seperate class

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

Right now I have my MainActivity.java that extends the Activity class.

```
package com.divergent.tapdown1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   View PlayScreen = new PlayScreen(this);
   setContentView(PlayScreen);
   PlayScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

This opens PlayScreen which extends View.
I want to be able to open the new LoseScreen that I created from PlayScreen when a certain event occurs. The problem is the setContentView() is obviously part of the Activity class. How can I get around this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
        if (playerBounds.bottom > rowBlock.top && playerBounds.top < rowBlock.bottom && (playerBounds.left < blockX1[row] || playerBounds.right > blockX2[row])) {

            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
            finalScore = score;

            parent.addView(new PauseScreen(getContext()));
            parent.bringToFront();
            parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebackground);

        }
```

Comment: why not use xml and update its view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take:

- You can create a container View (e.g. a `FrameLayout`), use it as your root view, and add the LoseScreen to it and remove the PlayScreen from it. You can then pass a reference to the container around if some other code needs to add/remove views.

  ```
  View playScreen = new PlayScreen(this);
  View container = new FrameLayout(this);

  playScreen.setRootView(container);

  container.addView(playScreen);
  setContentView(container);
  ```
- You can pass a reference to `MainActivity` to the class that creates the LoseScreen. Since `setContentView` is a public method, you can then just call `setContentView` on it, e.g.:

  ```
  Activity mainActivity = this;
  playScreen.setMainActivity(mainActivity);
  ```

  Then from within `PlayScreen`:

  ```
  mainActivity.setContentView(new LoseScreen(getContext()));
  ```

- From within `PlayScreen`, you can get the parent view using `getParent()` and then, similar to the first approach, add the LoseScreen to it and remove the PlayScreen.

  ```
  ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)getParent();
  parent.addView(new LoseScreen(getContext()));
  parent.removeView(this);
  ```

Comment: Thanks :D That worked, if I wanted to say just draw another screen over my play screen so my game is still showing (ex. pause screen) how would I do that?

Comment: Create another view that doesn't fill the screen, e.g.width/height set to specific values or wrap_content, and add it using addView

Comment: I can create the view but it doesnt draw my translucent background over my game view

Comment: If the view is being covered by something else, try calling bringToFront on it. If you want a translucent background, try using an 8 digit argb value for the background color, e.g. #80ff0000 for a 50% transparent red. If the problem is that it fills the entire screen, try reducing the width/height

Comment: I have tried calling the bringToFront function and it didnt fix it. I have updated my code to show where I am attempting to do this.

Comment: The problems seems to be that you're running the methods on the parent view instead of on the pause screen view. Save the pause screen to its own variable (before adding it to the parent) and then run the methods on the pause screen instead of the parent.

Comment: Should I put it somewhere other than my ondraw method? It keeps drawing the transparency over the transparency until its not transparent